# Discord.JS UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, typeerror

I'm currently trying to implement speech recognition into a discord bot, but I keep running into errors. I'm also new to Discord.JS and programming as a whole.

I copied some of the following code from an event file that interprets normal messages instead of speech, and it works fine there.

The following line throws an "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined": `if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;`

My entire file:

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    name: "join",
    description: "Joins the VC that user is in",
    async execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        const connection = await voiceChannel.join();

        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('Join a VC retard');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send("You don't have the correct permissions");
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send("You don't have the correct permissions");

        connection.client.on('speech', msg => {
            console.log(msg.content);
            const prefix = 'yo bot ' || 'Aries ' || 'Ares ' || 'yobot ';
            if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;

            const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
            const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

            const command = client.commands.get(cmd);

            if (command) command.execute(client, msg, args, Discord);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what is the msg in the ```connection.client.on('speech', msg =>```  function?

Comment: When I log msg.content to the console, it prints exactly what I say, but then prints the error a second later.

Comment: Yes I understand, but that's why I was asking for ```msg``` and not ```msg.content``` to see if ```msg``` has property ```content``` in the log like others said.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the message content is defined, before reading it's `startsWith` property. You can do this with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```js
if (!msg?.content?.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;
```

`msg?.content?.startWith(prefix)` will return undefined if either:

- `msg` does not have a `content` propery
- `content` does not have a `startWith` property

Answer (score 0):

If message content is not a string then you cannot use that function.

You need to check if message content exists first:

```js
if (!msg.content 
    || !msg.content.startsWith(prefix)
    || msg.author.bot
   ) {...}
```

Comment: When I log msg.content to the console, it prints exactly what I say, but then prints the error a second later. Would that prove that its a string?